# How to merge two tables in sql using inner join but without a common value in both tables

Tags: sql, database, join, mysql-workbench

i have two tables in my database and i want to merge the two using an inner join - there is a unique in both tables which have same names but different data so i cant use that column as the data is different in the primary key column!
Also i cant use a union operator because i want most of the columns from the first table and second table
How can i merge the two tables?
here is the code snippet of what am i trying to do:

Note: (the farmercode in table one has different values to farmercode in table two though the column name is the same and also a primary key)

```
SELECT  base.stationCode ,
        base.Farmercode ,
        base.Farmername ,
        base.POcode ,
        base.Sex ,
        base.DateofContract ,
        CONCAT(a.InspectionDate1, a.InspectionDate2) AS Internal_inspectionDate ,
        a.UnderstandingOfCertification ,
        a.TotFarmAcreage ,
        a.CoffeePlots ,
        a.CoffeeAcreage ,
        a.ArabicTrees ,
        a.ProductionEstimateFarm ,
        a.Tel ,
        a.InspectorName
FROM    kcl_baseline_2015_final AS base
        INNER JOIN main AS a ON ( base.farmerCode = a.farmerCode )
```

Comment: How do you join two tables properly if you don't have a relation between them (unless you are using cross join)? It is not the column names that are used to join two tables, but the column values (which are different as you are saying).

Comment: okay...i know about the cross join!

Comment: Specify *how* you want to "merge" the tables, i.e., what data should be returned where. Which fields should be equal in both tables? - Note that you can join *any* field to *any* other field, no matter if one is a PK or not.

Comment: from the select statement above: i just need the data from the columns <from the two tables>specified from the two tables simple. i could have used a join but i doesnot output a correct result.

Comment: @King14: If you use cross join, you will get a cartesian product of those two tables (any to any). Not what you are looking for right now. I would suggest improve your database structure by adding proper PK and FK.

Comment: Sure, but you *must* specify how each *row* from the first table is matched to a row from the second; or use a union if you only want to return both table's data one after the other.

Comment: Please provide an example of your table's data and what the result should look like.

Comment: the union operator doesnot help me much. it only picks the column names from the first select query and ignores the new columns in the second select query

Comment: The result should look like so:  stationcode<tableA>|farmercode<tableA>|POCode<tableA>|Sex<tableA>|StatusCertification<tableB>|Farm Area<table B>| Coffee Area<tableB>

Comment: I think we got that. But still: What *data* do you expect for each of the columns in *one single row*?

Comment: i am not so sure i understand your question but the answer is a Yes!

Comment: i just need the data from the two tables -- i dont care if i am using a join or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

As per the basic criteria, in order to merge two tables there should be a relation between them. But as in your case the relation cannot be established as both the fields might have different data.
So, you can either go for cross join without using ON condition or UNION ALL operator.

---

Edit 1:
If you want to merge to tables even if they do not have same no. of columns. Then you can define psuedo columns with alias like given below,

```
SELECT Column1, '' Column2 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Table2;
```

Edit 2:
If you want to merge to tables where you have different columns and want to display all. Then you can use psuedo columns as,

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, '' Column3, '' Column4 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT '' Column1, '' Column2, Column3, Column4 FROM Table2;
```

Comment: the union all operator will not work -- it only picks the column names from the first select query and ignores the new column names in the second select. PLEASE note i said: column names. otherwise it picks all the data and merges the two tables. in my case, i want all the columns specified from the two tables

Comment: i am not concerned with the number of columns in that sense. check this example query; select col1, col2 from tab1 union all select col3, col4 from tab2. when i run that query, i need to see: col1, col2, col3,col4 in my result set with all the data.

Comment: But the union/union all operator only does: col1 col2 and then appends all data below. Note: I need to see 4 columns not 2 columns!

Comment: Yes. The above method of using psuedo columns can be used for what you have mentioned. Check the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

(Preliminary answer for what I guess the OP is asking. Will edit once the question is clarified.)

```
SELECT
  a.x, a.y, a.z,
  b.o, b.p, b.q
FROM my_first_table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN another_table b ON 1=2 -- don't want any data, just the column definitions!
UNION
SELECT
  NULL, NULL, NULL,
  b.o, b.p, b.q -- only the data from the second table.
FROM another_table b
```

Comment: quick qn:  about that primary_key is null... is primary key - a unique column and from which table, mytable a or mytable b?

Comment: `primary_key` is just a placeholder I made up for any colum which does not allow `null` values.

Comment: so i tried to execute this sql query:select a.FarmerName, a.Farmercode 
from kcl_baseline_2015_final a 
left outer join main 
as b 
on a.FarmerCode is NULL
union
select b.UnderstandingOfCertification, b.CoffeePlots 
from main as b 
left outer join kcl_baseline_2015_final 
as a 
on b.FarmerCode is NULL;

Comment: and i got this output like so: <farmername>, <farmer code> with all the data showing at the bottom.

Comment: when you use the union -- it doesnot create column names from the second select operatoe because it expects them to be the same! in my case they are not the same!

Comment: You are aware that there can only be *one* column name per column in the result?

Comment: Yes am aware, which is why i chose the join - statement instead. I want all the columns showing up in my result so no unions allowed!

Comment: You want all columns from table1 and table2 in your result? That's what you get from the above. So what's wrong about my proposal?

Comment: okay. Lemme clarify; i want the result to show me 4 columns not just 2 columns. fine its getting me all the data but the UNION operator doesnot gimme the answer i need. Lets stick to the joins!

Comment: Also there is nothing wrong about yo proposal --- just not the query i need! #Danke again!

Comment: The example above gives you columns `x`, `y`, and `z` from `mytable1`, plus columns `o`, `p`, and `q` from `mytable2`. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: have you executed this in a normal mysql running enviroment and seen this query output 4 columns?? and also would you explaining me what the query does? Its kinda complex. in a way!